# Get Facebook login details in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, facebook-login

I am trying to make a **"Continue with Facebook" button** using  **JavaScript**, but I am not able to store returned details in my code behind using **C#**.

I have tried using **asp:HiddenField**, but it doesn't work. Also, using a **div** and then getting **innerHtml** returns me **"\r\n"**.

My code by now :

```
  function testAPI() {
                   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                   FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                         console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);                          
                         document.getElementById('status').innerText =
                         'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
                   });
  }
   <div id="status" runat="server"></div>
```

In my page **it shows the content of div**.
 But when I am trying to put it in a asp:Label, in order to use the details, it  returns null. I am using `lblStatus.Text = status.InnerHtml`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** 
I solved it adding an asp:button and firing click event when getting details in my javascript function. In this way, **server side will come after client side has already set value of my div**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the asp tags are rendered on **server side** before the page is sent to the client. Your testAPI() funtion is javascript and it is executed on the **client side** after that the page is received by the client and therefore that all asp tags are already rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to do this using this method.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark my answer as the correct answer to your question :)